# Don't understand why the simple regular expression doesn't match

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I expect the following pattern:

```
pattern1=r"\Ar(evolution)?ide\bthe\b(earth)\Z"
```

to match:

```
string=r"ride the earth"
```

Instead the following pattern is matching:

```
pattern2=r"r"\Ar(evolution)?ide \bthe\b (earth)\Z"
```

As `\b` is the blank, why isn't pattern 1 matching the string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\b` isn't a space; it matches the empty string at the beginning or end of a word.

`\s` is a whitespace character, so `r"\Ar(evolution)?ide\sthe\s(earth)\Z"` would match.

Answer (score 0):

**\b** is not *blank*, it is *break* instead:

> \b Matches a word boundary position between a word character and
>   non-word character or position (start / end of string).

If you need to match space you need to use **\s**:

> \s Matches any whitespace character (spaces, tabs, line breaks).

Answer (score 0):

Read [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)

> Matches the empty string, but only at the beginning or end of a word.
>   A word is defined as a sequence of word characters. Note that
>   formally, \b is defined as the boundary between a \w and a \W
>   character (or vice versa), or between \w and the beginning/end of the
>   string. This means that r'\bfoo\b' matches 'foo', 'foo.', '(foo)',
>   'bar foo baz' but not 'foobar' or 'foo3'.

So "\b" means not to stick to other words, but it matches empty but not space.